# Android Code for change activity when swipe left/right

Tags: android

i am very new in the world of programming.And also my English is very weak. But i want to know the code for this. I created a project for Math (AP,GP,HP) series. Now i want to set-up this like Whatsapp have Calls,Chats,Contacts.What should i do? Also Whatsapp has a white line under Calls/Chats/Contacts.that code for it?

Comment: You are looking for Tabs. https://material.io/guidelines/components/tabs.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/

use this link ,it will help you to make tabs, and after that take one relative layout and take one textview in that. I hope that will help !!!